# Composition of relations and function composition with different domain and codomain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

In Velleman's "How to Prove It" (2nd ed.), the composition of
relations $R\subseteq A\times B$ and $S\subseteq B\times C$ is defined
by
$$
S\circ R=\left\{ \left(a,c\right)\in A\times C\mid\exists b\in B\left(\left(a,b\right)\in R\land\left(b,c\right)\in S\right)\right\} ,
$$
and by Theorem 5.1.5, if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, then $g\circ f:A\to C$.

But the [other source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)
says that a function composition can be defined for the functions
$f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$ when $B\subseteq C$. I try to prove the
following theorem similar to Theorem 5.1.5, merely from the definition
of the composition of relations by the book, but I failed since the
composition of relation is only defined for the subset of relations
with the same codomain of $R$ and the domain of $S$.

**Theorem**. Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$. If $B\subseteq C$, then $g\circ f:A\to D$.

Is it possible to prove the above theorem merely from the definition,
or do we need some updated definition of the composition of relations?

#### Edit 1 (Mar. 28, 2021)

Based on the given hint, I tried the proof using the slightly updated definition of the composition of relations.

**Definition**. Suppose $R\subseteq A\times B$ and $S\subseteq C\times D$ are relations.
Then we define the composition of $S$ and $R$ by
$$
S\circ'R=\left\{ \left(a,d\right)\in A\times D\mid\exists b\in B\left(\left(a,b\right)\in R\land\left(b,c\right)\in S\right)\right\} .
$$
Merely for notional clarity, I used the different symbol $\circ'$
here.

I used the following fact.

**Lemma**. Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq A$. Let $f|_{C}=f\cap\left(C\times B\right)$.
Then $f|_{C}:C\to B$ and for all $c\in C$, $f\left(c\right)=f|_{C}\left(c\right)$.

Then we can prove the following theorem.

**Theorem**. Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$. If $B\subseteq C$, $g\circ'f:A\to D$.

*Proof*.

Suppose $B\subseteq C$. By Lemma, $g|_{B}:B\to D$. We will prove
$g\circ'f=g|_{B}\circ f$, from which we can conclude $g\circ'f:A\to D$.

- ($\to$) Suppose $\left(a,d\right)\in g\circ'f$. Then we can choose
  $b\in B$ such that $\left(a,b\right)\in f$ and $\left(b,d\right)\in g$.
  Then $d=g\left(b\right)=g|_{B}\left(b\right)$ by Lemma, so $\left(b,d\right)\in g|_{B}$.
  Therefore, $\left(a,d\right)\in g|_{B}\circ f$.
- ($\leftarrow$) Suppose $\left(a,d\right)\in g|_{B}\circ f$. Then
  we can choose $b\in B$ such that $\left(a,b\right)\in f$ and $\left(b,d\right)\in g|_{B}$.
  Then $d=g|_{B}\left(b\right)=g\left(b\right)$ by Lemma, so $\left(b,d\right)\in g$.
  Therefore, $\left(a,d\right)\in g\circ'f$.

#### Edit 2 (Mar. 31, 2021)

In fact, we don't need another definition. If $f:A\to B$ and $B\subseteq C$, $f$ can also be considered as a function from $A$ to $C$, so $f:A\to C$. Then applying Theorem 5.1.5, $g\circ f:A\to D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Paul Frost has made it more complicated than necessary.  If $R \subseteq A \times B$, $S \subseteq C \times D$, and $B \subseteq C$, then $R \subseteq A \times C$, so the original definition of composition can be applied to $R$ and $S$.  There is no need to change $S$ to $S'$ as described in his answer.

In fact, if $R \subseteq A \times B$ and $S \subseteq C \times D$, then even without the assumption that $B \subseteq C$, you could define $B' = B \cup C$, and then you have $R \subseteq A \times B'$ and $S \subseteq B' \times D$, and the original definition of composition applies.  This was not explained in the first two editions of How To Prove It, but in the 3rd edition there is an exercise that discusses this: Section 4.2, exercise 15, on p. 190.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $S \subset C \times D$ is a relation and $B \subset C$, then $S' = S \cap (B \times D) \subset B \times D$ is a relation and $R \circ S'$ is defined. Moreover, if $S$ describes a function, then $S'$ describes the function $f \mid_{S'} : S' \to D$.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question based on your hint.